# How to write an i-breve (an i with a breve accent, but without the dot)

Tags: accents

If I try something like `\u{i}`, I get both the breve and the dot. How can I get it without the dot?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: this is a pretty basic question. i suggest reading a good introduction.  "the not so short introduction to LaTeX2e" (`texdoc lshort` if you're using a system based on tex live) is a good place to start.  this topic is addressed on p.24 in the section "accents and special characters".

Comment: How come `\u{i}` doesn't do what you want, but `\'i` seems to work fine? (For me at least).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The dotless i is `\i`; so you would want `\u{\i}`. (A dotless j is, likewise, `\j`).

Comment: On math mode one should use `\imath` and `\jmath`.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio but in math it would be `\breve` not `\u`

Answer (score 5):

Use math simbols:

```
\breve{\imath}
```

Or

```
\breve{\jmath}
```

\breve is the accent and \imath / \jmath are i / j without the upper dot

Answer (score 2):

In the modern toolchain, with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, load `fontspec` and all of the following will work, along with several others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\mibreve{\textnormal{ĭ}}
\newcommand\mitibreve{\textnormal{\itshape ĭ}}

\begin{document}
ĭ \u{i} ^^^^012d \symbol{"012D} {\char"012D} \( \mibreve\, \mitibreve \)
\end{document}
```

In a legacy 8-bit engine, you can still use the precomposed character ĭ (U+012D), but not the combining accent ◌̆.  You can define `\u{i}` to give you `\u{\i}` instead with `\DeclareTextCompositeCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\u}{T1}{i}{\u\i}

\newcommand\mibreve{\textnormal{ĭ}}
\newcommand\mitibreve{\textnormal{\itshape ĭ}}

\begin{document}
ĭ \u{i} \( \mibreve\, \mitibreve \)
\end{document}
```

This would also work in OT1.